# is_const doesn't work as expected for reference

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, constants

I wrote a test program:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <type_traits> 
using namespace std; 
template<class T> 
void f(T&& t) 
{ 
     cout<<is_const<T>()<<endl; 
     //++t; 
} 
int main() { 
     const int i=0; 
     f(i); 
     return 0; 
}
```

It outputs "0", showing `T` is not const! This is weird. Then I modified `f`:

```
template<class T> 
void f(T&& t) 
{ 
     cout<<is_const<T>()<<endl; 
     ++t; 
}
```

Then there's compiler error, saying we're modifying a read only `t`.
So is `t` modifiable or not, at all? Is there any mis-assumption in my program?

Comment: @101010 The usage is correct. [`is_const`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const) has a suitable conversion operator.

Comment: @juanchopanza thanx for the info I didn't know that.

Comment: @juanchopanza what in `cout<<is_const<T>()<<endl;` would coerce it to bool?

Comment: try `is_const<std::remove_reference<T>>::value`

Comment: @xaxxon Well, there's no `ostream& operator<<(ostream&, is_const<T>)`, so there isn't much to pick from.

Comment: In case you're interested in learning _all about_ type inference - including why `T` is _not_ a reference type - consider [_Effective Modern C++_ by Scott Meyers](http://www.amazon.com/Effective-Modern-Specific-Ways-Improve/dp/1491903996/) which explains it _completely_ and _understandably_ (type inference and a whole lot more).

Answer (score 15):

See [std::is_const](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const):

> If `T` is a const-qualified type (that is, const, or const volatile), provides the member constant value equal true. For any other type, value is false.

`t` is declared as a [forwarding references](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference#Forwarding_references). So for your code, `T` will be deduced as `const int&`, which is a reference. Reference can't be *const-qualified*, it won't be const itself. Precisely, there's not *const reference* (i.e. `int& const`), because reference couldn't be rebound again. `const int&` is a reference *to `const int`*; and note that `t` is thus not modifiable.

From the standard, [$8.3.2/1 References [dcl.ref]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.ref#1)

> Cv-qualified references are ill-formed except when the cv-qualifiers
>   are introduced through the use of a typedef-name ([dcl.typedef],
>   [temp.param]) or decltype-specifier ([dcl.type.simple]), in which case
>   the cv-qualifiers are ignored.

More examples from [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_const#Example):

```
std::cout << std::is_const<int>::value << '\n'; // false
std::cout << std::is_const<const int>::value  << '\n'; // true
std::cout << std::is_const<const int*>::value  << '\n'; // false
std::cout << std::is_const<int* const>::value  << '\n'; // true
std::cout << std::is_const<const int&>::value  << '\n'; // false
```

Answer (score 4):

Whether `t` is modifiable is dependent on the type of `T` which is deduced based on the type of variable passed in.  In this case you're passing in a `const int`, so `t` is of type `const int &` because you're accepting it as a forwarding reference.

As far as why `is_const` is returning false, that's because `T` a reference type and references are never const.

Answer (score 3):

Your template function (i.e., `f`) takes as a parameter a [*forwarding reference*](https://isocpp.org/blog/2012/11/universal-references-in-c11-scott-meyers) (a.k.a *universal reference*). The rules that determine the deduction of `T` are refereed as [*reference collapsing rules*](http://thbecker.net/articles/rvalue_references/section_08.html). These rules are summarized bellow:

> 1. `T&`  `&`  becomes `T&`
> 2. `T&`  `&&` becomes `T&`
> 3. `T&&` `&`  becomes `T&`
> 4. `T&&` `&&` becomes `T&&`

Now, according to the reference collapsing rules, when you supply as parameter to `f` `int const i`, `T` will be deducted to `int const&`.

According to the C++ standard table 52 **`is_const` would evaluate to `true` if `T` is `const` qualified**.

[image]

Furthermore, in the C++ standard *§20.13.4.3/p5 Type properties [meta.unary.prop]* there's the following example of how `is_const` type trait works:

> [Example:
>
> ```
> is_const<const volatile int>::value // true
> is_const<const int*>::value // false
> is_const<const int&>::value // false
> is_const<int[3]>::value // false
> is_const<const int[3]>::value // true
> ```
>
> — end example ]

As you can see at the third line which is our case `is_const` evaluates to `false`. Why? Because the type passed in to `is_const` as a template parameter is a reference type. Now, references are inherently `const` in the sense that you can't change what they refer to, but they are not `const` qualified. Thus, `is_const` with a reference type will evaluate to `false`.

Answer (score 0):

The top-level answer is that *references* aren't cv-qualified. Only the types they refer to can be cv-qualified.

But this is one of those times when the placement of the word `const` matters. When you call:

```
template<class T> 
void f(T&& t)
```

with an lvalue of type `const int`, what does `T` get deduced to? You might say `const int&` (which is correct), but it looks like that type is `const (int&)`. Hence the possible confusion about `T` being `const`.

But if instead you said it deduced as `int const&` (which is the same type as before), here there's no possible confusion and it's perhaps less surprising why `std::is_const<int const&>` is `std::false_type`.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution could be to intercept const type in overload:

```
template<class T> 
void f(T&& t) 
{ 
     ++t; 
} 

template<class T> 
void f(const T& t) 
{ 
     std::cout << "const here" << std::endl;
}
```

Then references to const objects will be handled by second function.